# How to remove the action attribute in the form_open_multipart() in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Is there a way that I can remove the action attribute in CodeIgniter?

The code would normally be like this:

```
form_open_multipart('person/add', $attributes);
```

I was hoping that I could omit the first parameter so that I could not have an action attribute in the mark-up.

Thanks for those who could help.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can but consider:

1) **The action attribute has a meaning and a function**, don't know why you want it out

2) You can always pass it an **empty string** :

```
  <?php echo form_open('');?>
```

or `<?php echo form_open_multiaction('');?>`

gives:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
```

In case you're really sure about this, just open up the `form_helper.php` file, located in `system/helpers/form_helper.php.`

Pick lines 59 - 65 :

```
$action OR $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
$form = '<form action="'.$action.'"';
$form .= _attributes_to_string($attributes, TRUE);
$form .= '>';
```

and change line 60 to

```
$form = '<form ';
```

form_open_multiaction() just picks the form_open() and adds the enctype attribute, so you change form_open() and you're set.
It's up to you now, I still fail to see why an empty action won't suffice to your goals.

Comment: Hi Damien, if I would do this, this could affect all the <form> elements right? Is there a way that I could just do this specifically to a single page?

Comment: @JagadMarx afaik no, but you can always make a custom helper with just that function, or with a modified copy of the original form helper, and load that instead