# how to set action attribute blank using form_open in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using form helper library to load form in ci views. the script i am using is

```
echo form_open('');
```

But when i am inspeting the form or having a look at page source it has set action attribute with base url. I want to set action attribute always blank when using form_open('') method. How can i get this behavior of form_open() method. Usually we set action like this when using ci standard

```
echo form_open('abc/login');
```

so is there a way to keep action attribute blank.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762886/how-to-remove-the-action-attribute-in-the-form-open-multipart-in-codeigniter

Comment: both doesn't set action attribute blank. I have already tried these.

Answer (score 1):

First of all load a view in your view page of form open

**View.php**

```
// Open Form 
<?php $this->load->view('your_directory_path/form_open'); ?>
```

Secondly add form open code in seperate file so it can be attached anywhere in view files.

**form_open.php**

```
<form method="post" id="XYZ_DEMO" name="XYZ_DEMO" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ABC XYZ">
```

like this you can set action attribute blank using form_open in codeigniter.

Comment: in this where we are using form_open method ?

Comment: whenever you have to initialize your form at that place use form_open method.

Answer (score 0):

First of load form helper in order to use `form_open()` method.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Or load helper in `application/config/autoload.php`.

Then set blank form `action` attribute in view. like this..

```
 <?php echo form_open('', array('id' =>'form_id', 'class'=>'form_class'); ?>
```

Comment: it adds form action, not blank that.

Answer (score 0):

Blank action points to current page so that you can use

```
echo form_open(base_url());
```

Comment: this sets base url in action attribute not the blank, you have any idea.

Comment: Why do you want to set this to blank. base_url() works similar as blank

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve by wanting the action attribute blank. 
If you look into CI's **form_open** function inside the form_helper:

```
function form_open($action = '', $attributes = '', $hidden = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    if ($attributes == '')
    {
        $attributes = 'method="post"';
    }

    // If an action is not a full URL then turn it into one
    if ($action && strpos($action, '://') === FALSE)
    {
        $action = $CI->config->site_url($action);
    }

    // If no action is provided then set to the current url
    $action OR $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());

    $form = '<form action="'.$action.'"';

    $form .= _attributes_to_string($attributes, TRUE);

    $form .= '>';

    /* MORE CODE */
}
```

you can see that if the $action parameter is not set, it will be set to the current url.

```
// If no action is provided then set to the current url
$action OR $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
```

that could be the reason why when you pass empty parameter to **form_open('')** the action attribute still has value.

wouldn't it hurt if you just use html's way?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form_upload_submit">
```

if you really really know what you want to do, go ahead and edit (which I don't really advise doing so) the form_open function inside the form_helper.php located in system\helpers\form_helper.php